# merged cells are broken after load/save

Tags: python, python-3.x, openpyxl

I am opening a .xlsm file using openpyxl abd updated some cells in it and then saved as .xlsm file.Now when I open the saved file I see that the cells which were merged in the original file are broken in new file.

the code which i am using is-

```
  from openpyxl import Workbook
  from openpyxl import load_workbook
  wb = load_workbook('Excel.xlsm',read_only=False ,keep_vba=True)
  ws = wb['K0 Reg Patch Util']
  ws.cell(row=42,column=3).value = 25
  ws.cell(row=43,column=3).value = 30      
  ws.cell(row=44,column=3).value = 24
  wb.save('Test.xlsm')
```

how to modify the code so that the file remains in the same format in the new saved file too. Right now with this code the cells which were merged in the original file are broken. How to resolve that because i dont want to destroy the structure in the original file.

I have tried saving the file with the same name then also the same problem is coming. Actually i have to save the file with the same structure but the updated values.Can you guys please help me with this??

Comment: See https://openpyxl.readthedocs.io/en/latest/styles.html#styling-merged-cells

Comment: Actually when i am opening a .xlsm file using openpyxl and closing it without even editing it the merged cells which were present in the original file are loosing their border.How to correct that-@Charlie Clark